# Is there a .wav file of this Enterprise D sound effect?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, sound-effects

After the command to fire phasers was issued, Worf would [hit the fire button](https://youtu.be/3yAlUTxkoWQ?t=44s). There was a sound effect of two short sounds..almost like a warning...then the camera would cut to the phaser array firing along with the phaser sound effect.

Does anyone know if there's a .wav file of that pre-fire confirmation sound or even what it's called?  It seems like it was something audible at tactical to confirm that the phasers were about to discharge, and something pretty important for the tactical officer to hear so they know the phasers are functional and about to discharge...yet I haven't heard or seen this console sound anywhere.

Comment: Restructure this as a question. It's hard to tell what you are really asking for, except possibly a sound file?  I believe you're asking if there is a pre-fire confirmation sound, though, and that's a valid question.

Comment: You're going to make a text notification of this, aren't you?

Comment: @Axelrod I just had the best idea, time to scour Star Trek soundboards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

http://www.stdimension.org/MediaLib/technologye.htm#federation

You're looking for "*Torpedo launch initiated*" sound effect under Federation, Ship systems. The file is called *torpinitiate.wav*

Comment: Those Cardassian effects are beautiful.

Comment: Please bear in mind that any sounds effects from Star Trek are likely under copyright and owned either by Paramount Pictures or another production company. It is doubtful that the linked site has any license for the audio clips, and if they do it more than likely is not transferable. For more reading: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1352/1234

Comment: @Xantec hmmm.... I wonder what now. I guess thas website has that sound only for archive purposes, a documentary, if you will, and that is covered under fair use. However fair use is not a law, but a legal defence - what now? Should I remove this answer? We don't know the copyright and license status for these files... Answer by Jeff Atwood says it's OK if it's a gray area, and this definitely is not clearly illegal.

Comment: @Petersaber - I wouldn't trouble yourself **in the slightest** about copyright. This falls well within fair use and SFF:SE (to the best of my knowledge) has never been subject to a takedown notice from anyone, let alone over a low quality WAV of a 30 year old sound clip.

Comment: I agree with Richard that you shouldn't need to remove it. If Paramount does go on the war path then they'll send a take down to Stack Exchange and the answer would be removed. I only meant to point out the questionable legality of downloading any files from the link for those that may be concerned by it.

Comment: In practice, not only will Paramount *probably* not go after you for this clip, but if you use it to make some kind of fan-film-like-thing *and do not make any money from said film*, they will probably also tolerate that in much the same way as they tolerate most fanfic.

Comment: Yep that's the fx I was talking about! No I wouldn't make an alert tone with it because that would be bad--naughty and wrong even.haha Actually I just wanted to see if there really was a wav file. The net is rife with phaser sounds and I was curious if anyone had the console sound...I mean it's kinda important as far as sounds go, esp for the bridge crew.